# Como hacer referencia a archivos dll en C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

He desarrollado varias DLL que uso constantemente en mis proyectos.
Para usar dichas DLL en Visual Studio las agrego desde la pestaña "Proyecto->Agregar referencias", y al momento de compilar el proyecto donde añadi dicha referencia crea el ejecutable del proyecto y una copia de la DLL.

Lo que quiero hacer es hacer referencia a la DLL pero que este en otra ruta para tener mejor organizado el proyecto , por ejemplo me gustaria que el ejecutable se encuentre en la raiz y las bibliotecas esten en un subdirectorio que se llame "bin".

El problema es que no encuentro la forma de indicarle a visual studio la ruta de donde se encuentra la DLL.

Comment: Esto es asi a proposito, para evitar lo que antes se llamaba dll hell. Si quisieras que se leyera de un repositorio general deberias agregarla a la GAC, pero no se recomienda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se hasta qué punto te merece la pena el esfuerzo, pero bueno, yo he realizado una prueba de concepto con las instrucciones que [indican aquí](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/837908/how-to-load-an-assembly-at-runtime-that-is-located-in-a-folder-that-is) y lo he conseguido.

No he optado por la primera opción que es cargarla en la GAC, ya que he leído por ahí que no es precisamente lo más recomendable.

En concreto, de la segunda opción la del fichero de configuración, primero hay que establecer un nombre seguro a las dll que quieres posicionar en otra carpeta, ya que necesitas tener la propiedad `publicKeyToken` y luego editar el fichero de configuración en concreto el tag `assemblyBinding`. Las instrucciones están claras en el enlace que te he dejado arriba.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ReferenciaDll.UnaLibCualquiera"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="d82184549e397a6b" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/temp/ReferenciaDll.UnaLibCualquiera.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

La tercera opción, que incluso me parece más "elegante", ya que no necesitas el nombre seguro, sería usando `AppDomain` mediante `AssemblyResolve`.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFrmReferenciaExterna
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Punto de entrada principal para la aplicación.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            CargarLibreriasExternas();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private static void CargarLibreriasExternas()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
        }

        private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            //This handler is called only when the common language runtime tries to bind to the assembly and fails.

            //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
            Assembly MyAssembly, objExecutingAssemblies;
            string strTempAssmbPath = "";

            objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            AssemblyName[] arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies.GetReferencedAssemblies();

            //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
            foreach (AssemblyName strAssmbName in arrReferencedAssmbNames)
            {
                //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
                if (strAssmbName.FullName.Substring(0, strAssmbName.FullName.IndexOf(",")) == args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(",")))
                {
                    //Build the path of the assembly from where it has to be loaded.
                    strTempAssmbPath = @"C:\temp\ReferenciaDll.UnaLibCualquiera.dll";
                    break;
                }

            }
            //Load the assembly from the specified path. 
            MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);

            //Return the loaded assembly.
            return MyAssembly;
        }
    }
}
```

Ya nos contarás por lo que te decantas

Comment: muchas gracias, lo realize conforme a la ultima opcion que presentaste, muchas gracias